# Laravel/Octane - How to set timeout on concurrently method?

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to set timeout on `Octane::concurrently` ?

```php
Octane::concurrently([
    fn () => User::all(),
    fn () => Server::all(),
    fn () => Model::all(),
    //...

]);
```

As you can see i have mutiple eloquent operation so its possible one of them take too long to execute, So i want to know is it possible to set timeout on this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of the `Octane::concurrently` method is the timeout in miliseconds:

```php
Octane::concurrently([
    fn () => User::all(),
    fn () => Server::all(),
    fn () => Model::all(),
    //...

], 5000);
```

See:
https://github.com/laravel/octane/blob/1.x/src/Contracts/DispatchesTasks.php#L19
https://github.com/laravel/octane/blob/1.x/src/Swoole/SwooleTaskDispatcher.php#L27
https://github.com/laravel/octane/blob/1.x/src/Swoole/SwooleHttpTaskDispatcher.php#L36
https://github.com/laravel/octane/blob/1.x/src/SequentialTaskDispatcher.php#L23